# How do I re-order images (by path) with php and sql?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have a few questions regarding moving and removing image (path and name) in a sql database.

Here's how I upload and name the images:

```
  if(count($_FILES['upload']['name']) > 0){
    //Loop through each file
    for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['upload']['name']); $i++) {
      //Get the temp file path
        $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i];

        //Make sure we have a filepath
        if($tmpFilePath != ""){
            //Grab file extension
            $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['upload']['name'][$i], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

            //save the filename
            $shortname = $name . "_" . $i . "." .$extension;

            //save the url and the file
            //Modify this to year, make, _, id, #
            $filePath = "images/" . $shortname;

            //Upload the file into the temp dir
            if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $filePath)) {

                $files[] = $shortname;
                //insert into db 
                //use $shortname for the filename

            }
        }
    }

} //end images
```

Then I take the $files[#] and insert the image name and path into the database and the image is uploaded into the images directory. My question would be, if I want to remove an image from the database or change the order it would be saved, how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

For removing from database, use `DELETE` statement:

```
DELETE FROM myTable where id='$id'
```

Or

```
DELETE FROM myTable where name='$name'
```

You need to be sure that you are trying to delete the correct row. If you don't have a primary_key, your `name` column should be `UNIQUE`.

About order, there is no order in your database, at least not explicit. If you need to have an order, add a column, let's say, `order` and query with `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable ORDER BY order ASC
```

You will not have any problem with gaps in your order using this.

Comment: The names are unique, I've left out a part of the naming process to keep things a bit more simple. I have a function that will query the database and display images in order, but this is re-used a lot and I don't want to make changes to that function to change the order of one or two images.